# Opencart: Is it possible to use a variable from one vQmod xml to another?

Tags: opencart, vqmod

**Opencart**: 1.5.6.5_rc
**vQmod**: 2.5.1

I have two vQmod xml:

- `/vqmod/xml/mymod1.xml`
- `/vqmod/xml/mymod2.xml`

I am aware that **vQmod** loads and executes the xml files in alphabetical order.
So if in **mymod1.xml** I have `$a1` variable, is it possible to use `$a1` variable in **mymod2.xml**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VQMod really doesn't play a factor in this. If you were to hard code the values in files, you'd have the same issue to overcome. You'd need to give more detail as to where the values are set/accessed but the short and simple answer is yes this is possible